# Page CSS is randomly adding padding to portfolio images

Tags: html, css, wordpress, padding

My team developed the portfolio website.

But we are facing with strange issue.

We pasted this issue in the theme support, but it is not yet solved.

While loading this [page](http://givereply.org/wp_adbp/projects/), it is giving sometimes like this:

[image: padding_image]

and sometimes like this(We want like this):
[image: required_image]

How to get rid of this??

Comment: not able to recreate the same issue.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner as I can see it happens only when switching categories.

Comment: It also depends on screen size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Wordpress but if you have access to the CSS that controls the template them maybe you can use Firebug or Inspect Element to find out if the upper and lower divs have any class specifications, and then set the margins to zero in the CSS file like this:

I'll pretend Firebug revealed div classes upperdiv and lowerdiv like this:

```
<div class="upperdiv">photos</div>
<div class="lowerdiv">photos</div>
```

in the CSS you could try:

```
.upperdiv {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.bottomdiv {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Hope this helps.